# How do I theme a menu to have a wrapper div with menu name?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

The default menu theme function doesn't output the menu name (see below).

```
function theme_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

I've inspected $variables, and that doesn't contain the menu name. Does anyone know how I can theme a menu so that its name is in a wrapper div?

Answer (score 5):

[`theme_menu_tree()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) is a theme wrapper function: it's called after the render array for the menu tree is rendered, and thus, after you have a chance to modify the rendered output.

Additionally, you can't pass any arbitrary data to a theme wrapper function: it'll always receive the rendered output of the children.

So to do what you want to do, where you have a wrapper `<div>` that has an ID, you need to modify the menu tree render array to call your own theme function that adds it.

#### Practical example

Let's say you're trying to do this for all menu blocks (a common use-case for menu trees): [`menu_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_block_view/7) populates the content of the block with [`menu_tree($delta)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7), where `$delta` happens to be the menu name corresponding to the block.

Now, `menu_tree()` calls [`menu_tree_output()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/7), which is where the render array that calls `theme_menu_tree()` is built.

So, what you want to do is modify the contents of the block after the render array is built, to replace `theme_menu_tree()` with your own theme function that adds your `<div>` with ID. To do that, implement [`hook_block_view_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  // Check to make sure this is a menu block
  if (in_array($block->delta, menu_get_names())) {
    // Replace the theme wrapper function with a theme function
    // and add the menu name to the render array
    unset($data['content']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $data['content']['#theme'] = 'MYMODULE_menu_tree_with_id__' . $block->delta;
    $data['content']['#menu_name'] = $block->delta;
  }
}
```

Replace `MYMODULE` with your module's short name. Once implemented, create the theme function `theme_MYMODULE_menu_tree_with_id()` to handle wrapper `<div>`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['MYMODULE_menu_tree_with_id'] = array(
    'render element' => 'element',
  );
  return $theme;
}

/**
 * Returns a menu tree with an id corresonding to the menu name.
 */
function theme_MYMODULE_menu_tree_with_id($variables) {
  $output = '<div id="' . $variables['element']['#menu_name'] . '">';
  $output .= '<ul class="menu">' . drupal_render_children($variables['element']) . '</ul>';
  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Very good! You can actually do that in your template.tpl. I made a https://gist.github.com/3201854 to show how I manage it...